# Compare Two Date columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want an answer to the question, show me all of the rows where `Est. Arrive` occurs BEFORE `Est. Ready`. (i.e. package shows up before we're ready to receive).

My query is showing me too many incorrect results. (Showing the 5 rows instead of the 1 row).

Both date columns are `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` (`datetime`) and I converted them to date only. Using SQL Server Management Studio.

```
Select Est. Arrive=convert(date,ETA_Arrive), Est. Ready=convert(date,ETA_Ready)  
from table  
WHERE ETA_Arrive < ETA Ready

Row # Est. Arrive      Est. Ready  
1     2020-07-13       2020-07-16   
2     2020-07-26       2020-07-16   
3     2020-07-28       2020-07-16   
4     2020-08-03       2020-07-16   
5     2020-07-22       2020-07-16
```

I want row 1 to be the only returned row:

```
Row # Est. Arrive     Est. Ready  
1      2020-07-13      2020-07-16
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When to comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Shouldn't you compare the converted values instead of the original (string?) values?

Comment: If you want rows where ETA_Arrive is _before_ ETA_Ready, you should do `ETA_Arrive < ETA_Ready`.

Comment: ETA_Arrive and ETA Ready columns date type?

Comment: @vc74 it won't matter for that presentation whether they're string or date

Comment: Updated Title - MSFT SQL Studio. Both date columns are yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, and I convert them to just date.

Comment: You should consider keeping the time.. surely if you're only going to be ready at 10am and the package arrived at 9am you want to know about it!

Comment: my role is to get the dates accurate, other teams smooth out the specific hours. And even though the date format has time....every value is 00:00:0000

Comment: Well, you'll have an issue if you chop the time off in the select but not the where clause! 2000-01-01 will be reported as being before 2000-01-01 when it looks like it isn't, til you realize the times you disposed of (in presentation only) were 9am and 10am respectively

Comment: How would I chop off the time in the Where clause? Have tried that a few times but SQL won't accept the 'friendly' column names (Est. Arrive) in the Where clause

Comment: The alignment of your data perturbs me. If you copypasta'd this then the data should align. Are there literally extra spaces at the start of your dates (your dates being erroneously stored as strings)

Comment: You use the original column names. Sales execute in this order: FROM, WHERE, GROUP, HAVING, SELECT, ORDER.  At the time the where is done the friendly names, "created" by the select, don't exist

Comment: all the extra spaces are because I typed out the table in SO. wasn't sure how to copy/paste with headers.

Comment: Pressing ctrl t will make SSMS output in text mode(press ctrl d to get back to grid mode), but tbh it would be easier for us at this point to see a screenshot of exactly what you're running, what results you're getting and what columns are in the table. See my comment on my answer for more info

Comment: are you sure you are not getting errors for the query that you are running ?

Comment: not getting errors. query executes successfully - but I rows that don't fit the criteria I'm after. Based on similar SO questions, I think this has something to do with date column structure, but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own (obviously)

Comment: I am trying very hard to believe its not giving you errors. Pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the rows where arrive is before ready you need to use `<` in your query, not `>` (or swap your ready and arrive over but keep the `>`)

You wrote:

```
WHERE ETA_Arrive > ETA Ready
```

Syntax errors aside, logically this means "where arrive is after ready". Turn it around

Comment: Soo... that kinda implies this doesn't answer the question. Curious to know why it doesn't!

Comment: My query has Est. Arrive < Est. Ready, but i copied it incorrectly to SO. sorry!

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your sql query tool open and showing clearly your full SQL and the results grid the sql generated. To take a screenshot on a Windows machine click start, search SNIP, use snipping  tool to capture a region, use pen tools to redact as appropriate,  press ctrl c, come to SO, edit your question, press ctrl v, wait for image to finish uploading to imgur, submit your edited question. Also make sure your screen shot shows an expanded database explorer, drilled down far enough to see the number and types of columns in the table

Comment: can't take a screenshot for privacy reasons. Updated the question & table with help from other users. Does that help?

Comment: Even changing the operator from > to < then will not solve the problem. "ETA Ready" will give errors anyways.

Comment: @VarunT that's why I said "syntax errors aside". The original assertion was that the query was running (which could notpossibly have been true if there was a syntax error) and returning too many rows . Don't rock up after we've been through a drawn out process of diagnosing the problem, and start trashing answers posted in response to the question as it was originally posed. Look at the edit histories, and see that the original query used `>` incorrectly etc

Comment: @JillHendrickson24 If you can't post a screenshot, I'm not sure how much more help we can give. The query as posted, if you amend the syntax errors as I have guided in the comments ("use the original column names not the 'friendly' ones"), will return rows correctly. You claim in your question that the query runs fine, but then youve posted code that is broken for syntax reasons and cannot possibly run at all. This is why I asked for a screenshot. I gave instructions on how to redact the screen contents; you can reduce it to no more than you've already posted, but I do need to see what you see

Comment: because the state of things as presented in the question cannot possibly be the state of things as presented on your computer; there must be a typo or other kind of error somewhere in the question or in SSMS. A screenshot is a direct presentation of the problem as you see it

Answer (score 0):

Your query will give errors as the alias are not defined properly. Check my query below. One more error is the eta_ready has a space. Please try to show some effort to generate pseudo code before posting incomplete answers.
[image]

```
WITH tbl(id,eta_arrive,eta_ready)
AS 
(SELECT 1 ,    '2020-07-13'  ,    '2020-07-16' UNION   
 SELECT 2 ,    '2020-07-26'  ,    '2020-07-16' UNION  
 SELECT 3 ,    '2020-07-28'  ,    '2020-07-16' UNION  
 SELECT 4 ,    '2020-08-03'  ,    '2020-07-16' UNION  
 SELECT 5 ,    '2020-07-22'  ,    '2020-07-16')

 Select 
 [Est. Arrive] = convert(date,ETA_Arrive), 
 [Est. Ready]  =convert(date,ETA_Ready) 
 FROM tbl  
 WHERE ETA_Arrive < ETA_Ready

 Est. Arrive    Est. Ready
 2020-07-13     2020-07-16
```

Comment: Hi Varun, thanks for the feedback - i'm trying to learn the best way to ask questions.  What is the purpose of the With/As/Union top half of your answer? I have 1000s of rows so I'm not sure if i can use that - since i would have to type out 1 line for each of the 1000s of Row #. I edited the original question - does it make any more sense?

Comment: WITH is just trying to create a Common table expression ( CTE) . You wouldn't need it as you would already have a table so you really need to use the other half part of the query.  Check this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The point is that you said you are getting 5 rows instead one however the query in your question will throw error in SQL Server. So you should clearly state that the query is throwing error as the screenshot I have shown.

Comment: @jillhendrickson24 the best way to ask questions is to supply the info you're asked for. You've written a question there and said "this query works but returns too many rows". Flat out no way at all the query you have posted, is a working query. It has a syntax error that means it will never, ever run. Even if it did run there is no way that sqlserver would assert that `2020-07-26` is less than `2020-07-13` no matter whether they're strings or dates. Hence either a) this cannot possibly be the exact query you are running or b) your claim that it runs and produces these results *must* be a

Comment: mistake, or c) your sqlserver has a serious bug that needs reporting to Microsoft immediately. A screenshot will straighten all this out; just post one, heavily redacted to show only the query window, results grid and table column names/types - nothing that you haven't already posted so no privacy concerns